# C# in VS2005: can you overload the .ToString() method of a property?

Tags: c#, properties, overloading

C# in VS2005: can you overload the `.ToString()` method of a property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - properties have a `get` method, which returns a value -- you can overload the implementation of `ToString()` on the type of that value, which will allow you to do:

```
myClass.MyProperty.ToString()
```

which is likely what you're looking for. Simply define a function such as:

```
public override string ToString() {
    // return string version of value
}
```

in that type's class.

Comment: That is unfortunate. A Property is like a wrapper object for a type, so I think you should be able to overload methods like ToString() to customise the string representation of a Property.